# Convert from character to date format

Tags: r, datetime

There are a lot of answers for this question, but I cannot seem to find the solution for my problem.
I have COPIED the daily stock data of GOOGLE from 4th March 2009 to 4th April 2019 to excel. Not only is the format of the dates character, but it has multiple formats. I am unable to convert it to the right format.

Can someone please help with the right code?

[This is the site from where I have copied](https://markets.businessinsider.com/stocks/goog/price/nas/4.3.2009_4.4.2019)

I understand that there would be much easier ways,but just to understand how to do this, I am asking this question.

This is the code:

```
> google <- read_excel("Mappe1.xlsx")
> head(google)
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  DATE      OPEN     `CLOSING PRICE` `DAILY HIGH` `DAILY LOW` `VOLUME (PCS.)`   
  <chr>     <chr>    <chr>           <chr>        <chr>       <chr>             
1 43528     1,208.28 1,205.92        1,216.30     1,201.00    406.91800000000001
2 43500     1,195.32 1,200.49        1,201.17     1,185.82    273.697           
3 43469     1,182.00 1,194.43        1,196.49     1,182.00    428.96100000000001
4 3/29/2019 1,174.90 1,173.31        1,178.42     1,163.00    536.81899999999996
5 3/28/2019 1,168.72 1,168.49        1,171.55     1,159.70    348.24299999999999
6 3/27/2019 1,185.50 1,173.02        1,187.10     1,159.37    489.28500000000003
```

Comment: So what date is `"43528"` supposed to be?

Comment: It is the date "2019/04/03", Year/Month/Date format

Comment: I think it is the date starting "01/01/1900"

Comment: Probably a formating issue with Excel? The date 43528 cannot be Linux seconds and line 4-6 are okay. So maybe have a look at your xlsx file. You could try to save the xslx to csv/text and import csv/text.

Comment: Does it work if you specify the column formats? read_excel("Mappe1.xlsx", col_types = c("date", rep("numeric", 5)))

Comment: When i try to specify column formats, it is giving NAs.

Answer (score 0):

[Step1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhPM4.jpg)

[Step2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNSrG.jpg)

[Option 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYS00.jpg)

Copy it from the main website and while pasting into excel do the above two steps, you will get proper date format according to your system format. Hope this is in order to clear your doubt.

Below formula also can be used(can be seen in option 2 image) to bring down the proper date format as per the data given by you.

=IF(ISTEXT(A3),DATE(RIGHT(A3,4),TEXT(LEFT(A3,FIND("/",A3)-1),"MM"),MID(A3,FIND("/",A3)+1,FIND("/",A3,FIND("/",A3)+1)-FIND("/",A3)-1)),DATE(TEXT(A3,"YYYY"),TEXT(A3,"MM"),TEXT(A3,"DD")))